# Validate multiple issuers in Azure APIM policy

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

The company I work for has acquired multiple products over the years.
We've been developing a shared microservice ecosystem.
The products (currently) authenticate to different IDPs (e.g. Auth0, Azure B2C).
The back-end microservices can handle multiple issuers just fine, but we also want to do authN checks at the API gateway - Azure APIM, and short-circuit if the JWT acces-token is invalid.

How do I validate multiple issuers in Azure APIM?

In the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-access-restriction-policies#ValidateJWT), I can see that I can specify multiple issuers, but there's only 1 openid-config. How would it be getting the public signing keys for multiple issuers if there's only 1 openid-config? Presumably it goes to this to get the JWKS endpoint and then the info to verify token signatures...

Here's part of the APIM (inbound) policy I'm talking about:

```xml
<validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Unauthorized" require-expiration-time="true" require-signed-tokens="true">
    <openid-config url="https://example-company.au.auth0.com/.well-known/openid-configuration" />
    <audiences>
        <audience>test</audience>
        <audience>blah</audience>
    </audiences>
    <issuers>
        <issuer>https://example-company.au.auth0.com</issuer>
        <issuer>http://contoso.com/</issuer>
    </issuers>
</validate-jwt>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to clarify; the company I work for has multiple products and each product has a separate IDP and/or tenant - basically there's no cross over of uses between products.

The `validate-jwt` policy only allows 1 `openid-config` element, but for my scenario I've got multiple OpenId configs...

I managed to get around this by doing the following:

```xml
<choose>
    <when condition="@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("X-ProductCode","") == "XYZ")">
        <validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Unauthorized" require-expiration-time="true" require-signed-tokens="true">
            <openid-config url="https://xyz.au.auth0.com/.well-known/openid-configuration" />
            <audiences>
                <audience>xyz-audience1</audience>
            </audiences>
        </validate-jwt>
    </when>
    <when condition="@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("X-ProductCode","") == "ABC")">
        <validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Unauthorized" require-expiration-time="true" require-signed-tokens="true">
            <openid-config url="https://abc.au.auth0.com/.well-known/openid-configuration" />
            <audiences>
                <audience>abc-audience1</audience>
                <audience>abc-audience2</audience>
            </audiences>
        </validate-jwt>
    </when>
</choose>
```

Answer (score 6):

This can be done by first decoding the token and adding a `when` condition on one of the claims BEFORE you validate it.

```
<set-variable 
   name="iss" 
   value="@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("Authorization", "")?.Split(' ')?.ElementAtOrDefault(1)?.AsJwt()?.Claims["iss"]?.FirstOrDefault() ?? "")" 
/>
<choose>
    <when condition="@(context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault("iss", "").Equals("myIssuer.com"))">
       <validate-jwt configuration1... />
    </when>
    <otherwise>
       <validate-jwt configuration2... />
    </otherwise>
</choose>
```

Answer (score 0):

APIM does read full OpenID connect config and linked JWKS to get list of keys and valid issuers. At the same time the sample you have should work just fine as well, issuers from OIDC and explicitly specified will be combined.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Maybe I'm missing something here, but how does it validate tokens from the second issuer in the list I provided - 'http://contoso.com' ? There's no corresponding OIDC config url (to get the public signing key from)...

Comment: Validating issuer and validating token signature are two different things. With configuration above policy will let tokens with issuer "http://contoso.com/" be treated as having valid issuer, but signature still needs to be checked. And above will only give policy keys from OIDC config to validate that. If you need to add more keys you can do so.

Comment: Hmm... can I add more openid-config? I don't think I can. I don't I'd want to explicitly add key information in APIM policies as IDPs could rollover to new keys at any time (and break my auth). I understand IDPs probably wouldn't do key rollovers very often, but if they ever do, I wouldn't want to have to go and  make changes in APIM to support this...